# Thead and tbody in same ruby (slim) .each cycle

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, each, slim-lang

Would anyone be so kind as to help me with a simpler/more elegant way of writing a table in an .erb file?

I currently have this:

```
table id="example-datatable"
      thead
        tr
          - Risk.column_names.each do |c|
            th
              = c.camelize

      tbody
        - @risks.each do |risk|
          tr
            td
              = risk.exposition
            td
              = risk.frequency
            td
              = risk.risk
```

Is it possible to use a single cycle and still keep table head and body separate?

Comment: One `.each` is iterating over column names whereas the other is iterating over row data. It's hard to imagine how you'd combine that into one `.each`. What you have looks extremely simple to me. You can't get much more elegant than a loop that says exactly what it does.

Comment: What you're requesting is actually far more complicated than what you currently have.

Comment: True, you are right guys, I just wanted to confirm, I am still learning and I was always curious if this could be made even shorter. Thank you for your time! ;)

Answer (score 0):

With what I see in the question, I'm assuming that there are 3 basic columns needed as follow:

- exposition
- frequency
- risk

If those are the only columns and this will be static, one thing you can do is to hard code the `thead` part of your table, and then loop through your records to populate the `tbody` as follow:

```
table id="example-datatable"
  thead
    tr
      th Exposition
      th Frequency
      th Risk
      th

  tbody
    - @risks.each do |risk|
      tr
        td
          = risk.exposition
        td
          = risk.frequency
        td
          = risk.risk
```

And that should solve it for you.